# Command for getting the file size

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, filesize

Could anybody please tell me a shell command for Windows 7 which would take a file path as argument and return the size of that file - Something like:

```
fileSize.cmd file.txt
```

...which will give me `1KB`.

One question in SO noted the command `echo %~z1`, but for this, I have to write a separate batch file and use this command in it. I was thinking of modifying my existing bat file and incorporate this command somehow. My batch file looks like this:

```
p4 diff //sources/j2cs/output.txt >> diff_out.txt
```

I have to add above command in the existing bat file to find the file size of `diff_out.txt`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need an extra batch file, you could move your filename into %1 with a call to a function or you can use a FOR loop.

```
call :getFilesize diff_out.txt
echo %fileSize%
exit /b

:getFilesize
set filesize=%~z1
exit /b
```

Or

```
for %%A in (diff_out.txt) do set fileSize=%%~zA
```

Answer (score 1):

another variant:

```
@echo off

set file=c:\bookmarks.html

%1 %0 :: %file%
set len=%~z2
echo %len% 

pause
```

or with wmic:

```
D:\>set wql="drive='g:' and filename='function2' and extension='txt'"

D:\>wmic path cim_datafile where %wql% get name,filesize
FileSize  Name
621       g:\function2.txt

D:\>
```

or:

```
set file=G:\function2.txt

echo set len=%%~z1 >_tmp.bat
call _tmp.bat %file% && del _tmp.bat
echo %len%
```